# I never get out from BluetoothSocket.connect()

Tags: android, bluetooth

Any idea what might be causing the issue? 
I execute the `connect()` function and no further code is executed.

CODE:

```
 void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-01 20:10:00.569  24445-24445/bluetooth.example.com.bluetoothserial D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-01 20:10:07.606  24445-24445/bluetooth.example.com.bluetoothserial D/BluetoothUtils﹕ isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
05-01 20:10:07.606  24445-24445/bluetooth.example.com.bluetoothserial W/BluetoothAdapter﹕ getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
05-01 20:10:07.626  24445-24445/bluetooth.example.com.bluetoothserial D/BluetoothSocket﹕ connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[61]}
05-01 20:10:08.086  24445-24445/bluetooth.example.com.bluetoothserial I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't having the right UUID, I solved it by obtaining the right UUID and then replacing it in the code.

How to obtain UUID:

```
ParcelUuid[] list = mmDevice.getUuids();
```